# What is the best procedure to remove an user from MySQL table, but keep their data in foreign tables?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

First of all, I found many discussions on this question around the web, but I'm really skeptical about the solutions proposed also mainly because most of them were from over 4 years ago when GDPR was novel, and also because they contradict each other a lot.

In order to be compliant with GDPR, we need to fully remove user's personal information (email, name, address, etc) when they request it.

In our system we have the table User and other tables like Training and Session for example.

Training has a ManyToMany relationship with User and Session table has an user_id field that is a foreign key to User table. Also Session has a training_id field which is also a foreign key to Training

I want to delete the users personal info that is contained in User, but I want to be able to keep their data in Session for statistics and log purposes.

I understand a hard delete is not the way to go, the fk constraints would be problematic and even though I could use Null, it's not really recommended. The suggestion I see more often is to just add a flag on User table to indicate if the user is deleted (is_delete) and use that appropriately in my business logic. IMO, that alone does not really resolve the problem with GDPR, as the user's info would still be in the database and this could get you in trouble with an audit and I was surprised this kind of answer was upvoted in most topics.

What I'm thinking of doing, it's to add that flag of is_delete, but also update the user row with fake or empty data to get rid of all user personal info. So I'd have something like this:

| ID | email | name | surname | address | is_deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "" | Anonymous | "" | "" | true |

Would this be sufficient? Do you guys see any flaw with my plan?

Comment: This is a debate with no winner, to be honest. What if the user returns, it requires constantly a new user in the user table while data would be the same for the returning user? And all of the sudden they cant use their account anymore? Do you check on emails if they excist? How can they view their old data if they decide to return and allowed to be viewed? I would somewhere store at least name and email and password somewhere as account details and remove the rest, and use the name "anonymous" only if is_deleted is true

Comment: Hmm, to be sure, you should first ask a lawyer, if keeping the other data, even if the main data is anonymized, is lawful in your case.

Comment: In short, it depends. You may want to keep correct data as well for some reporting purposes.

Comment: Deleted personal information means deleted. The point is to make it impossible for a skilled cybercriminal or data-mining specialist to tell the user was ever on the system. A user who requests deletion will  permanently lose access to the deleted account.

Comment: With respect, I do not believe the answer to this question is a matter of opinion. The requirements for removing PII are clear and the ways of removing it from database tables are straightforward.

Comment: I think it's really a pity to close this question and say it's a matter of opinion.  I came with a problem and a potential solution and asked if that solution would make sense or if people had alternate solutions to it. A question about how to optimize some code would have different solutions from different people. Would that be an invalid SO discussion? I disagree.  And I know this overlaps a bit with the legal realm, but we as developers are constantly required to adapt to business. This is a rather new scenario change and we should be able to talk about how to handle it in different ways

Comment: @O.Jones the problem is that the crux of the question (is this fine under GDPR) is not a programming question, it is a legal one. Although I **think** the OP and yourself are correct in the approach, I don't think this is the right forum (programmers as audience) to provide guidance on this.

Comment: @RafaelSantos whether your approach is correct or not is a legal question in this case, not a programming one, therefore your question is not for SO. Opinion based is probably not the best way to close it, I agree, but I don't think this is on topic here.

Comment: I'm not asking if this is fine under GDPR or try to raise a debate on it. In fact my wording is very clear that I'm aware what is and what is not GDPR compliant ("...that alone does not really resolve the problem with GDPR...") .Other people in their answers were debating that, but that was not the point to my question. My question in short is : how to fully delete specific user info fields, but keeping other non-personal info for logs and stats purposes. But I think @O.Jones answer was already helpful, so at least for me it doesn't matter much. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're right. UPDATEs to rows with personally identifiable information is the way to do this without messing up your database constraints.  You may want to change one of the PII columns to say "Redacted at (date-time)" in case some auditor wants to see evidence that you comply with these requests.

It takes a while to get your changes to filter through to all your backups. There's not much you can do about that operationally except making sure you don't retain old backups too far back in time.

If you use PII as a primary, unique, or constraint key, that's a problem. For example, if you use email address as a key to user information, you may have to replace the values in those columns with a randomly-generated text string to erase the data and preserve the uniqueness. You'll have to do that in a way that preserves constraints.

Don't forget that your web server logs very likely allow you to find users' IP addresses given their user IDs.  Be sure you set up a log retention policy (ten days?) and enforce it by automatic deletion.

Make your policy say "it may take up to thirty days to completely delete..." to give your workflows time to affect your server logs and backups.

If a user asks you to remove all data, and then later returns to use your service again, handle them as a user you've never seen before. If you *could* figure out that you had seen them before, you obviously did not delete all their PII when requested.

Comment: Unfortunately, the legal requirement is that the PII must be erased from backups or the backup has to be put "beyond use" (you cannot use it to restore the deleted PII data). But I think this goes way beyond the scope of a standard SO answer.